# Android map v2: marker in a wrong position

Tags: java, android, double, marker

I've got problems in setting markers into my app.
I create my LatLng object and add it to the map; latitude and longitude have 6 digits after comma.
The problem is the following: where i get the position of each marker on my map (with myMarker.getPosition.latitude and myMarker.getPosition.longitude), values have much more than 6 digits after comma (about 15 digits), and the values differ from input ones. (ie. input latitude is 40.254874, output latitude is 40.25487358741045).

Does anyone can help me??

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot represent arbitrary floating point numbers in Java.](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/) My guess is that the difference is due to this.

Note that the discrepancy is at most 11 centimeters (111.321km / 1e6).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sotiris try this code.

```
     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(53.551, 9.993)).title("Test"));
```

It will be better if you round the values after decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the implementation. You may see / star it on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5353). I guess the reason might be double values are stored in some other way when transported to Google Play Services and back.

Basically this blocks comparing `Markers` via position `LatLng`, so you should use a different way to compare them (e.g. `Marker.equals`).